# Where to delete?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm having quite a hard time deciding on the best way to delete my derived classes here. I currently have the following layout:

```
class Tag {
   // Stuff
   // [...]
   void releaseMemory(Tag *t);
};

class TagByte : public Tag { /* [...] */ };
class TagShort : public Tag { /* [...] */ };

Tag::releaseMemory(Tag *t) {
    switch (t->getType()) {
       case TAG_BYTE:  delete (TagByte *)t; return;
       case TAG_SHORT: delete (TagShort *)t; return;
       // [...] many more
    }
}
```

The reason I am doing this is that there are more complex tags like `TagCompound` which will contain tags of different types, and all of those are stored as a `Tag *`. Inside the destructors `~TagCompound`, `~TagList` I do call `Tag::releaseMemory();` on every tag, because `delete` on a `Tag *` would only free a `Tag` and not the actual `TagWhatever`, thus resulting in a memory leak.

The other option I had thought of was adding a new virtual method to every derived class, so every child of `Tag` would have it's own `releaseMemory()` instead of one combined in the super class.

Then I wondered whether I'm already starting off bad on the design level by assuming everything passed into the complex types `TagCompound` and `TagList` is a *heap* object to which I also couldn't find a better solution, because this whole construct is part of a parser for something that looks like this (just binary and not as verbose):

```
TAG_Compound("Root"): 4 entries
{
  TAG_String("Name"): Test
  TAG_Short("SomeNumber"): 21
  TAG_Double("..."): 9000.5
  TAG_Compound("Eek!"): 2 entries
  {
    TAG_String("Marco"): Polo
    TAG_List("Names"): 3 entries of type String
    {
      TAG_String: Hello
      TAG_String: World
      TAG_String: Segfault
    }
  }
}
```

And dynamically reading that on runtime doesn't play well with instances on the stack.

What can I do to make this... I don't know.. elegant?

Comment: Why not use an overloded releaseMemory member function ? I think that would suffice if I have got your question right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, you just [declare a virtual destructor in the base class](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7).  This plays nice with both stack and heap allocation.  In case of polymorphic delete, the compiler figures out the true type and calls its destructor.

Comment: That is actually less complicated than what I was doing, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This design really breaks the idea of encapsulation. Tag should never know that TagByte exists. The destructor for Tag should be marked as virtual as should the destructor of each derived class. Release allocated variables for each level in the appropriate destructor. At destruction everything will be cleaned up in the correct order with no memory leaks. My feeling is this design is bad from the start and you should read up on destructors and inheritance.

Comment: Yep, I thought so, too, that's why I decided to better ask people who know better!

Answer (score 1):

C++ actually offers very elegant solution to this - virtual destructor. Even more, every polymorphic type should have one. GCC even has a warning level for this `-Wnon-virtual-dtor`.